# UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification NSNotification not working in iOs 8

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios8, nsnotificationcenter

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(youTubeStarted:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(youTubeFinished:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification" object:nil];
```

UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification NSNotification not working in iOs 8

Answer (score 5):

i am also faced the same problem but finally ended with using  `UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification` and `UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification`, for embedded  youtube videos(assuming by looking at your selector method names)

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(enteredFullScreen:) name:UIWindowDidBecomeVisibleNotification object:nil];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(exitedFullScreen:)  name:UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification object:nil];
```

above is a patch work around,(hope this helps)

Answer (score 0):

I use `MPMoviePlayerController` and it works fine. I guess that depending what you are using it for, you don't need `UIMoviePlayerController`.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(youTubeFinished)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification
                                               object:self.player.moviePlayer];
```